# CSS and HTML: How to create an Expanding DIV On Click?

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

I need to create a DIV that has some content (some of which is hidden) and when you click on it, it expands and reveals the rest of its content..

I have found many HOWTOs but use jQuery....

I would like a solution using CSS and HTML (Javascript is good also!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do realize that jQuery is a JavaScript library?

Comment: Hmmm... I am not Familiar with jQuery.... Thanx for the Info! :-)

Comment: However, I would like a solution that accepts CLASSES.. What I found with jQuery, is ONLY with IDs....

Comment: May be it's better if you learn about Jquery. Then ask question

Comment: That is what I will probably do soon....

Comment: To be fair, @sandeep He is asking for Javascript and there is no rule in development that you have to use JQuery. JQuery is just a library. I disagree with your comment about not asking a question cause he clearly mentions he does not want to use JQuery

Comment: You can select with class, with id, and many many other selectors! Here's what selectors are available: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Imo: jQuery is even easier to learn than JavaScript. And yes, you can use classes in jQuery.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your Helpful comments! 
I will use the solution that prash posted! Be sure that I will check all the helpful Links you commented!

Comment: @Wiz my comment about OP misconceptions about Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

css

```
#sample {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("sample").onclick = function() {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
}
```

you can use some jquery for animated div

Comment: OK! Thanks! I think this is ok!